# Connecting to peers but not loading any blocks

Tags: synchronization

I start Bitcoin Core as admin and last week everything worked as it should, 
but now it is stuck at 93% and tells me it is connecting to peers. 
In the end I waited 5 hours and it happend nothing.

Where is the problem.

Thanks